# Reading large number of images in python using opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am making a food classification program using machine learning models.I have avery large data set of 101 classes and each class has around 1000 images but working with such a large dataset has caused me to run out of memory hence I used a smaller data set and I found the classifier to be biased for one training class.I am using cv2.imread() to read the images and then I have used scikit to train and test the models. my code is as follows

```
def image_to_feature_vector(image, size=(128, 128)):
    # resize the image to a fixed size, then flatten the image into
    # a list of raw pixel intensities
    return cv2.resize(image, size).flatten()

def extract_color_histogram(image, bins=(32, 32, 32)):
    # extract a 3D color histogram from the HSV color space using
    # the supplied number of `bins` per channel
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv], [0, 1, 2], None, bins,
        [0, 180, 0, 256, 0, 256])

    # handle normalizing the histogram if we are using OpenCV 2.4.X
    if imutils.is_cv2():
        hist = cv2.normalize(hist)

    # otherwise, perform "in place" normalization in OpenCV 3
    else:
        cv2.normalize(hist, hist)

    # return the flattened histogram as the feature vector
    return hist.flatten()



class_names=[]
read_images = []
# initialize the raw pixel intensities matrix, the features matrix,
# and labels list
rawImages = []
features = []
folders = glob.glob('E:\\food\\images\\*')
imagenames__list = []
for folder in folders:
    for f in glob.glob(folder+'/*.jpg'):
        imagenames__list.append(f)
        image=cv2.imread(f)
        #plt.imshow(image)
        a=os.path.basename(folder)
        class_names.append(a)


        pixels = image_to_feature_vector(image)
        hist = extract_color_histogram(image)# add the messages we got to the raw images, features matricies
        rawImages.append(pixels)
        features.append(hist)



print(class_names)
print(f)            
rawImages = np.array(rawImages)
print(len(rawImages))
features = np.array(features)
print(len(rawImages))
class_names = np.array(class_names)
```

Can you suggest any changes to the code so That I can use the full dataset.Please point out if this approach is completely wrong and how do I change it.

Comment: can you briefly describe your method? What kind if data is user in the teaining, what kind of classifier etc. In general, you can compute the minimum needed memory if that kind of classifier training must have all the data present at once and if that's already too much, you'll have to switch to different input type (features) or use an out-of-core classifier training instead.

Comment: I am using two classifiers KNN and support vector machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like follows to use all images you have for the training process. This code is for gray scaled images. You have to make relevant changes as per your requirement.

```
def load_train(train_path, image_size, classes):
    images = []
    labels = []
    img_names = []
    cls = []

    print('Going to read training images')
    for fields in classes:
        index = classes.index(fields)
        print('Now going to read {} files (Index: {})'.format(fields, index))
        path = os.path.join(train_path, fields, '*g')
        files = glob.glob(path)
        for fl in files:
            image = cv2.imread(fl,0)
            image = cv2.resize(image, (image_size, image_size), 0, 0, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
            image = image.astype(np.float32)
            image = np.multiply(image, 1.0 / 255.0)
            image1 = image.reshape(50,50,1)
            images.append(image1)
            label = np.zeros(len(classes))
            label[index] = 1.0
            labels.append(label)
            flbase = os.path.basename(fl)
            img_names.append(flbase)
            cls.append(fields)
    images = np.array(images)
    labels = np.array(labels)
    img_names = np.array(img_names)
    cls = np.array(cls)

    return images, labels, img_names, cls
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could comment some parts of the code

Comment: How would this solution avoid running out of memory? I think one need to use a generator or sth to read images in chunks and write on the disk.